# what is the use of keeping a list of all activities in an android application?

Tags: java, android

I came across below `ApplicationManager` class in someone‘s code. This class basically keeps a list of all activities started.

I checked throughly and found that this class is used only in below 2 circumstances:

1. in `oncreate()` of every `activity`: `ApplicationManager.getInstance().addActivity(this);`   to add the activities started to the list.
2. `ApplicationManager.getInstance().applicationExit();` is called to finish every activity on the list when the application is closed.

So here is my question...  Is this actually needed?? What if I do not do this, what is the consequence? Will the activities in the app still occupy memory after the app is closed?

Thanks!!

```
public class ApplicationManager {
    private List<Activity> activityList = new LinkedList<Activity>();
    private static ApplicationManager appManager;

    /**
     * singleton
     */
    public static ApplicationManager getInstance(){
        if(appManager == null){
            synchronized (ApplicationManager.class) {
                if(appManager == null){
                    appManager = new ApplicationManager();
                }
            }
        }
        return appManager;
    }

    /**
     * add Activity
     */
    public void addActivity(Activity activity){
        activityList.add(activity);
    }


    /**
     * application exit
     */
    public void applicationExit(){
        if(WPApplication.DEBUG){
            Log.i("applicationExit", "alist:" + activityList.size());
        }
        while(activityList.size() > 0){
            if(WPApplication.DEBUG){
                Log.i("applicationExit", "remove--");
            }
            activityList.get(0).finish();
            activityList.remove(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No its not needed. Application class will be a singleton Instance for your application. You can get all running Activity list using package manager.

Comment: App may leak memory while running but when it is closed, memory is taken back by the OS. The only "memory used by the app" after closing may be the ROM, in the Android Log file.

Answer (score 1):

No. Never ever ever do this.

This is just a recipe for memory leaks. The Android system can shut down any Activity at any time and this class would keep a handle to them all whether they exist or not.

Garbage collection would fail to run because the handles are keeping the objects "alive"

Also consider this:

Rotating a device causes an Activity to restart (calling its OnCreate again). Every time you rotated the device, the activity would be recreated and a new pointer added to the list. All the other pointers to the same activity are essentially dead but taking up memory. Every single view inside every single activity will be kept alive as their context (the Activity) still has references stored.

You could actually run out of memory by just constantly rotating the device.

Comment: What if it had a "removeActivity()" method?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage application lifecycle. No matter how many activities are open at the same time, you could close app with `applicationExit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this, the only benefit on your sample is to kill all activities at once.

The scenario is very rare and not recommend in most case.

If you really want to do this you can call `Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

Comment: This goes against the Android Activity lifecycle and should almost never be done.

Comment: Isn't it possible for an app to spawn children processes and make them session leaders, leading to killing everything but the newborn and independant processes (aka daemons)?

Comment: most case you can use startActivity with intent flag to do this @hdl